# Jquery wont work in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

This is probably a simple question to answer but my Jquery wont work on my theme at all no matter what tutorial ive followed.

my js file is located as /js/jquery.js and the code inside is just for testing purposes:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


$('#banner').hide();
});
```

my functions.php file is located in the same location as the index is and the code ive done for that is:

```
    <?php
function add_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'jquery', // name your script so that you can attach other scripts and de-register, etc.
        get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/jquery.js', // this is the location of your script file
        array('jquery') // this array lists the scripts upon which your script depends
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
?>
```

and nothing happens... can anyone correct me in what I am doing wrong? This is what puts me off using wordpress.

Comment: Is this a theme, plugin, or what

Comment: no just custom jquery

Comment: then you probably don't need to include jquery at all. wordpress does that for you.

Comment: well... since you're trying to get into code, please open up your browser console and check to see if there are errors. also look at the network tab in that console to see that jquery has in fact loaded.

Comment: http://www.matthewclaffey.com/ the banner is meant to be hidden but it does nothing though?

Comment: @KevinB I don't believe his jquery.js file contains jQuery itself. It contains jQuery code instead. With that said, probably a good idea to rename it to something else.

Comment: You get some clues from the Browser Dev Tools, for example, you can check if jQuery is really loaded, if your code hasn't errors, etc. You code appears to be right.

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  alert("test");
});
put this in your js file and check whether alert is popuping or not

Comment: oh sorry @KevinB it is Jquery code not Jquery itself I should of mentioned that. Ill try renaming it.

Comment: Ah, ok. In that case, naming your script `'jquery'` when you do `wp_enqueue_script` is probably a very bad idea.

Comment: ive renamed it to my_js now and still nothing. I think I may have made a school boy error. I havent added the script src in the index.php file. XD Note - Just added that in and still error

Comment: you shouldn't need to add the script src to index.php, wp_enqueue_script does that for you. I'm unsure about the action you are using though.

Comment: I am willing to try any other method.

Comment: you should also check if your .js file should load after the jQuery library file.

Comment: I fixed my problem i missed out the wp-head()

Comment: How do I fixed that margin that wont go away? matthewclaffey.com

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you need to have a slash before "js":

`get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.js'`

With that said, you could check your site using the network monitor in your browser's developer tools. It will show you what URLs are being fetched. Or maybe just check your developer tool's console. It could show you a 404 error if it is unable to fetch your jQuery file.

Comment: I have added the lash and it did nothing.

Comment: I was pretty sure that was your issue, but no problem. Could you check the developer tools?

Comment: I am very new to wordpress... what is developers tools and where abouts is it? XD

Comment: You could use Chrome and check [this](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/index)

Comment: i have used the sources bit on developers tools and it does not seem to load the file

Comment: I fixed it with adding <?php wp_head(); ?> inside <head></head> tag

Answer (score 0):

```
wp_enqueue_script(
    'call this something else!', // name your script so that you can attach other scripts and de-register, etc.
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.js', // this is the location of your script file
    array('jquery') // this array lists the scripts upon which your script depends
);
```

you had a couple of typos.....also check if jquery is available by using your dev.console in chrome or firefox(right click on page, click inspect element, and then console) you'll get a error jquery undefined or similiar.

Also on your page in frontend:

```
get_header();
get_footer();
```

you dont use the head tags as these functions pull in the header file & footer files. without get_header() & get_footer - you'll have issues :)